# Use $(window).height as Animation Value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass of the window height as the value for animation with no luck in this jQuery function. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

below is my code and a fiddle.

```
$("slice").onclick().animate(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        var theHeight = $(window).height();
        top: '+=theHeight',
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rH4JJ/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need something like that?

```
$(".slice").click(function () {
    var theHeight = $(window).height();
    $(this).animate({
        top: '+=' + theHeight
    });
});
```

​
**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rH4JJ/4/

Yes, to make sure, in the above example `position: relative` style was added to `slice` elements. Otherwise, changing `top` makes no sense.

Comment: @JoeIsaacson You are welcome! That was funny to see the flag of my country in your example :D

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work because it's completely nonsensical in about six different ways.

```
$('.slice').click(function() {
    var theHeight = $(window).height();
    $(this).animate({
        top: '+=' + theHeight
    });
});
```

You also have to give the `slice` elements `position: relative` in order to be able to animate their position.

Comment: @VisioN: Yeah, that was actually a useful takeaway for me.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to VisioN's answer, note that you'll need to give the elements a position to start with (note they added postion:relative to the css in that fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn CSS (width is 100% for a div), jQuery and jsFiddle (select jQuery on select in sidebar)

```
$(".slice").on("click",function(){
    var theHeight = $(window).height();
    $(this).animate({
        top: "+="+theHeight
    });

});
```

Edit : I put the Div in absolute (usually) but relative is better from your example. 
http://jsfiddle.net/rH4JJ/16/